# Excel COM Exception when invoking SaveAs method

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, comexception

In my C# code, I firstly open an Excel file:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(modelFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Then I edit it.

Finally I save it in a different path called `fileName`:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName);
```

The problem is that if `fileName` corresponds to an opened Excel file, the instruction above fires the COM Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
ErrorCode=-2146827284
HResult=-2146827284
HelpLink=xlmain11.chm
Message=Unable to access 'MyFile.xlsx'.
Source=Microsoft Excel
```

Please note that I don't have the same problem with the `xlWorkBook.Save()` method, but I need to save the edited file in a different path and not to override it.

Comment: Well you cannot SaveAs to a file thats already open.  You need to close the existing file (which will then be overwritten) or save to a different name.

Comment: Why I can't do it? The Save() method allows to save to an opened file...

Comment: @you need to check whether any file with the same name exists or not, and if there is add "2" to the end of it and try again, and if it existed, then increment one more until you get to a name that does not exist and you can save it under that name. In VBA you can use function DIR() to retrieve file names in a folder

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save to an open file. You would have to modify fileName so it points to another path.